# Scrapy Returns Inconsistent Results

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I'm trying to scrape an Amazon product page but scrapy is giving me inconsistent results (sometimes it returns what I want and sometimes it returns None). I have no idea as to why the same code give different results. I created a loop that yield the same request 10 times and it was giving me different results. Can anyone help me?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

class AmzsingleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amzsingle'

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(10):
            yield Request(url="https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929", callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath('//span[@id="productTitle"]/text()').get()
        }
```

and this is the log that I get in the terminal. This attempt gave 9 None and 1 found (some other time it was returning 7 None and 3 found):

```
2021-11-27 22:08:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 22:08:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 22:08:30 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{'title': None}
2021-11-27 22:08:32 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 22:08:33 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{'title': None}
2021-11-27 22:08:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 22:08:35 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{'title': None}
2021-11-27 22:08:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 22:08:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{'title': None}
2021-11-27 22:08:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 22:08:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{'title': None}
2021-11-27 22:08:39 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 22:08:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{'title': None}
2021-11-27 22:08:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 22:08:40 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{'title': None}
2021-11-27 22:08:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 22:08:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{'title': None}
2021-11-27 22:08:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 22:08:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{'title': '\n¡Avancemos!: Student Edition Level 3 2013 (Spanish Edition)\n'}
2021-11-27 22:08:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 22:08:45 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{'title': None}
2021-11-27 22:08:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-11-27 22:08:45 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 4664,
 'downloader/request_count': 11,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 11,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1508328,
 'downloader/response_count': 11,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 11,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 20.82323,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 27, 15, 8, 45, 324091),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 7323320,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 11,
 'item_scraped_count': 10,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 22,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'memusage/max': 53161984,
 'memusage/startup': 53161984,
 'proxies/good': 1,
 'proxies/mean_backoff': 0.0,
 'proxies/reanimated': 0,
 'proxies/unchecked': 0,
 'response_received_count': 11,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 10,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 10,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 10,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 10,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 27, 15, 8, 24, 500861)}
2021-11-27 22:08:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Why are you using range? why not inject the loop i into url? if so the url will be invalid, Because the url contains only one title and according to your selection the output is correct. The url doesn't contain next pages.

Comment: The use of range was just for demonstration purpose that the same code returned different results

Answer (score -1):

You can use a CSS selector.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

class AmzsingleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amzsingle-parse'

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(10):
            yield Request(url="https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929", callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.css('#productTitle ::text').get()
        }
```

**Output**

```
{"title": "\n\u00a1Avancemos!: Student Edition Level 3 2013 (Spanish Edition)\n"}
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{"title": "\n\u00a1Avancemos!: Student Edition Level 3 2013 (Spanish Edition)\n"}
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{"title": "\n\u00a1Avancemos!: Student Edition Level 3 2013 (Spanish Edition)\n"}
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{"title": "\n\u00a1Avancemos!: Student Edition Level 3 2013 (Spanish Edition)\n"}
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{"title": "\n\u00a1Avancemos!: Student Edition Level 3 2013 (Spanish Edition)\n"}
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{"title": "\n\u00a1Avancemos!: Student Edition Level 3 2013 (Spanish Edition)\n"}
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 15:56:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{"title": "\n\u00a1Avancemos!: Student Edition Level 3 2013 (Spanish Edition)\n"}
2021-11-27 15:56:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929> (referer: None)
2021-11-27 15:56:42 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.amazon.com/%C2%A1Avancemos-Student-Level-2013-Spanish/dp/0547871929>
{"title": "\n\u00a1Avancemos!: Student Edition Level 3 2013 (Spanish Edition)\n"}
```